# Spring MVC - Configuration : Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [default-servlet-handler]

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

i have a problem with Spring MVC.

An exception BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [default-servlet-handler].
If in the file beans.xml i have mvc:default-servlet-handler. 
If i remove it: no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see your xml, but barring that, it sounds like you simply have a classpath issue. Make sure `spring-webmvc-VERSION.jar` is in your classpath at runtime. If you are using maven, it would look something like this in your pom:

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${your.spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
...
```

That jar contains the namespace utils, including the proper parser, for the `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` element (amongst others.)